# How can I find which program is making a specific network request?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, network-monitoring

I have 2 Windows Server 2003 boxes that sit idle, for the most part, on weekends. Yet when I look at my router's DNS logs, both machine's are making many requests for www.yahoo.com when there's nobody using the machine.

None of the programs that run in perpetuity make any requests to Yahoo that I know of. The requests happen at a rate of slightly more than 1/minute.

Is there a way that I can find out which program or service running is making these requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install Microsoft Network Monitor. Start a Capture. Filter the Capture for DNS, HTTP and HTTPS. Look at the captured results. NetMon will list each process responsible for it's corresponding network traffic, which should allow you to track it down. Granted that the DNS client process is going to be responsible for any DNS related traffic relevant to Yahoo, which isn't going to tell you the "why" of it, but filtering for HTTP and HTTPS should allow you to see what other processes may be trying to connect to Yahoo.

Comment: Now called "Microsoft Message Analyzer"

Comment: And now "Microsoft Message Analyzer" is retired. MS recommends Wireshark. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/blog/ms-winintbloglp/dd98b93c-0a75-4eb0-b92e-e760c502394f

Comment: P.S. Microsoft Network Monitor is still available to download and working https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=4865

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to enable certain debugging in the Windows DNS server in order to gather who is making the request:

[image]

Pick things like `Details` as well.

You might also need to use Wireshark or Netmon to capture the packets in order to fully understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Install **netstat** for windows. This program shows you active TCP connections and their associated process ids (pid). Associate the pid with the program name in the Task Manager to determine which program is making the connections.

For example:

```
c:\>netstat -anb 
TCP    0.0.0.0:8081           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2044
[FrameworkService.exe]
```

(note others are correct, netstat is a built in windows command, no need to install anything)

Comment: ? Netstat doesn't need to be installed. Netstat is a built-in tool.

Comment: @joeqwerty well, "activated" or whatever. sometimes these things need to be activated in windows before you can use them. telnet, for one, always bites me